# overflow and height does not work in my container

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll

This is  my problem I aim to have a responsive layout a search bar and 5 container with different height I want to have the height with % to keep the responsitivity and if the text is much more than it must to be we must add the scroll with the axis is y and x for me that doesn't work have you got any idea what is wrong

this my html code :

```css
.green {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1%;
  max-width: 98%;
  max-height: 45%;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
  height: 5%;
  // overflow-y: scroll;
  //max-width:70%;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
  // max-height: 45%;
}

Title {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: 'fontLufga';
  margin: 1%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.view-home--searchInput {
  background-image: url(/assets/searchIcon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px center;
  padding-left: 3%;
  /* Adjust this value based on your image size */
  font-family: 'fontLufga';
  font-size: 20 px;
  width: 39%;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  height: 5%;
  /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    background-position: 10px center;
    padding-left: 13%;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.view-home--searchInput:focus {
  outline-color: #41A9A7;
}

.Container {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  //max-height: 45%;
  min-height: 100 vh;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.scrollable-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  // overflow-x: auto;
  // max-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-8 col-md-12 Container">
  <input type="text" class="view-home--searchInput" placeholder="Search" />
  <h1 class="Title">Overview</h1>

  <div class="row green">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">overview</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1 overflow-auto">test test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-2 red">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1">test3</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To make the content scrollable within the containers, you need to set the overflow property to auto and specify a max-height for the containers.

height in percentage for the containers, you can use the **`vh`** unit.

Wrap your content inside a container element, such as a  with a class of "container" or any other appropriate class name. This will help with centering the content and maintaining responsiveness

modified HTML and CSS:

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row green">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">overview</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1 overflow-auto">
      test
      <!-- Add your content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-2 red">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1">test3</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  margin: 1%;
  max-width: 98%;
}

.green {
  background-color: white;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Hope this solution should help you achieve a responsive layout with a search bar.

**`New Answer`**

Updated CSS code:

```
.green {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1%;
  max-width: 98%;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
}

.view-home--searchInput {
  background-image: url(/assets/searchIcon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px center;
  padding-left: 3%;
  /* Adjust this value based on your image size */
  font-family: 'fontLufga';
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 39%;
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  height: 5%;
  /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    background-position: 10px center;
    padding-left: 13%;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.view-home--searchInput:focus {
  outline-color: #41A9A7;
}

.Container {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.scrollable-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Updated HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-8 col-md-12 Container">
  <input type="text" class="view-home--searchInput" placeholder="Search" />
  <h1 class="Title">Overview</h1>

  <div class="row green">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">overview</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1">test test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br> test test test <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-2 red">
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 block1">test3</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 block2">test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thannks so much ! but i have questions if u don't mind first why it works with vh and it doesn't with % . second if i use vh i noticed that the height of other component of page or the nav bar are expanded and changed

Comment: @user22 Using vh (viewport height) instead of % for the container height allows the container to scale based on the height of the viewport. The percentage height (%) is relative to the height of the parent element, while vh is relative to the height of the entire viewport. In your case, using % for the container height may not have worked as expected because the parent element's height was not explicitly defined, leading to unexpected behavior.

Comment: When using vh for container heights, it's important to consider the overall structure and other components of your page. Setting a specific height for a container in vh will take up a percentage of the viewport height, potentially affecting the positioning and layout of other elements on the page, such as a navigation bar. To avoid unwanted expansion or changes in other components, you may need to adjust the heights of those components accordingly or consider using a different approach, such as using flexbox or grid layouts, to achieve the desired responsive design